# Creating a recurring calendar event with php-ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am trying to create a recurring calendar event with php-ews and the documentation is very limited in this aspect. I have got what is below so far I just can not find out how to have it repeat say every Monday and Wednesday. Can anyone who has done this before or knows how help me out?

```
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence = new Type\RecurrenceType();
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->WeeklyRecurrence = new Type\IntervalRecurrencePatternBaseType();
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->NumberedRecurrence = new Type\NumberedRecurrenceRangeType();
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->NumberedRecurrence->NumberOfOccurrences = 2;
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->NumberedRecurrence->StartDate = //start date here;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used this...

```
// Set up recurrence days
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence = new EWSType_RecurrenceType();
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->WeeklyRecurrence = new EWSType_IntervalRecurrencePatternBaseType(); 
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->WeeklyRecurrence->Interval = 1;
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->WeeklyRecurrence->DaysOfWeek = new EWSType_ArrayOfStringsType();
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->WeeklyRecurrence->DaysOfWeek = array(EWSType_DayOfWeekType::MONDAY, EWSType_DayOfWeekType::WEDNESDAY, EWSType_DayOfWeekType::FRIDAY);                
        // Specify recurrence start and end
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->EndDateRecurrence = new EWSType_EndDateRecurrenceRangeType(); 
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->EndDateRecurrence->EndDate = '2014-05-30'; 
        $request->Items->CalendarItem->Recurrence->EndDateRecurrence->StartDate = '2014-05-14';
```

Looks like you're just missing the `DaysOfWeek` array item.  Adjust your array as needed based on the days you'd like the meeting to occur, and of course set your own start and end dates as well.  I believe the `Interval` item would be equivalent to 1=every week, 2=every other week, etc. but i have not tested that.